# Каннибализация ключевых слов

Tags: seo, оптимизация-сайтов, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

Что такое каннибализация ключевых слов в принципе понятно, когда содержание страницы, в том числе мета-теги title, h1, description совпадают.

Но хотелось бы спросить мнение опытных пользователей на частном примере двух тайтлов при разном содержании страниц - общая категория "дверные ручки" и подкатегория "дверные ручки на круглой накладке".

title №1 дверные ручки - купить....в таком то магазине...
title №2 дверные ручки на круглой накладке - купить...

1. Будет ли Title №2 ранжироваться по фразе "дверные ручки" ВЧ запрос или только "дверные ручки на круглой накладке" НЧ запрос?
2. Стоит ли в №2 убрать слово "дверные" или хвост ключевого слова делает его уникальным?
3. Как в таком случает с карточкой товара поступить? "Дверная ручка...такая то модель" или "Ручка ....такая то модель"

Comment: @edem «каннибализация» это не только про людей, а вообще про все случаи когда подобное пожирает подобное. Термин, может, не самый лучший, но он понятен SEO-шникам в отличие от «сравнения». Пожалуйста, обращайте внимание на контекст при редактировании.

Answer (score 0):

> Будет ли Title №2 ранжироваться по фразе "дверные ручки" ВЧ запрос или только "дверные ручки на круглой накладке" НЧ запрос

Может ранжироваться, но вряд ли будет.

> Стоит ли в №2 убрать слово "дверные" или хвост ключевого слова делает его уникальным

В общем виде - не стоит. А в вашем конкретном случае - неизвестно. Может у вас там вовсе переспам и нужно полностью чистить теги и контент.

> Как в таком случает с карточкой товара поступить? "Дверная
>   ручка...такая то модель" или "Ручка ....такая то модель"

Смотрите свою семантику. Как ищут пользователи, так им и пишите/показывайте.